# Why am I getting different output when I manually compile and run the code as compared to automatic compiling and running by IDE

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, notepad++

The following program separates out the Urdu string from regular English strings. I wrote this program

```
    try {
     File f = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/tes.txt");
     FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
     String text = "";
     String s;
     while( ( s = br.readLine() ) != null) {
       text += s;
     }

     String splits[] = text.split("سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے");

     for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(splits[i]);
     }  
} catch(Exception exc) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
  }
```

in *notepad++* compiled it , and ran it to get this output :

```
∩╗┐╪│┘╣█î┘à┘╛ ╪«╪¬┘à █?┘ê ╪¼╪º╪¬█î █?█Æ

suhail

╪│┘╣█î┘à┘╛ ╪«╪¬┘à █?┘ê ╪¼╪º╪¬█î █?█Æ

gupta

╪│┘╣█î┘à┘╛ ╪«╪¬┘à █?┘ê ╪¼╪º╪¬█î █?█Æ

cse

╪│┘╣█î┘à┘╛ ╪«╪¬┘à █?┘ê ╪¼╪º╪¬█î █?█Æ

ghazal

╪│┘╣█î┘à┘╛ ╪«╪¬┘à █?┘ê ╪¼╪º╪¬█î █?█Æ
```

when the file `tes.txt` looked something like this :

[image]

but when I run the same program from netbeans IDE I get the expected output which is :

```
suhail
gupta
cse
ghazal
```

What does difference does it make when I run the same program after writing in notepad++ and then compiling it using the command :

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 checker.java
java checker
```

and copying the same program in the netbeans IDE and pressing the run button ? In the first case string does not split from the regex `urdu string`.

Comment: You should pass the encoding of the file to be read in the FileReader ctor.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How : **java checker**  Where : **Windows,java 1.7.0-ea** , where checker is the name of the class file

Comment: can you give a sample. But then if this is the issue why am I getting the correct result when I use the netbeans IDE ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Might be that the netbeans console uses a different charset by default...?

Comment: @cHao will this sort of application be portable ? And why does JDK console doesn't keep the unicode standard ?

Comment: @mP: There is no `FileReader` constructor that accepts encoding as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileReader` and `FileWriter` classes implicitly use the system's default character encoding.

Try reading with `InputStreamReader`

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    while(br.ready())
    {
        text = text+br.readLine();
    }
```

**Edit:**

1)  Change the encoding of the prompt : `chcp 65001`

2) Specify Charset in the constructor of `InputStreamReader`

```
 import java.io.*;

public class UnicodeTestFile{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

try {
     File f = new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/tes.txt");
     InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"UTF-8");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
     String text = "";
     String s;
     while( ( s = br.readLine() ) != null) {
       text += s;
     }

     String splits[] = text.split("سٹیمپ ختم ہو جاتی ہے");

     for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(splits[i]);
     }  
} catch(Exception exc) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
  }}
}
```

3) Compile it by specifying the encoding

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 Checker.java
```

Comment: can you have a look at the code [here](http://i49.tinypic.com/zsqr0z.jpg). Please check the red-marked statement. what should be the offset and the third argument which is the maximum number of characters to read .

Comment: @SuhailGupta: `Offset` is from where you want to store your characters. Instead of reading like this, wrap it using a `BufferedReader` and then read. Look I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still it doesn't print the urdu text. Instead I get question marks for the urdu text. And what mistake I made in the code snapshot i showed you

Comment: Change the encoding of your console. Go to Run Configuration > Common > Console Encoding . Change the default cp-1252 to UTF-8.

Comment: I did not find the path. where is `configuration` ?

Comment: Its in eclipse menubar. "Run configuration"

Comment: eclipse ? Why are you telling me about eclipse ? How do I change the default encoding for the command prompt in windows ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: oops sorry. Just Right click > Properties > Font > Select Lucida console(its a unicode font)

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Type chcp 850 on your command prompt and then check

Comment: @SuhailGupta: You compiled it by specifying the encoding right ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: I will try at my end. Can you paste the actual .txt file ? What I see in the OP is a screenshot I believe.

Comment: yeah i specified the encoding `javac -encoding UTF-8 checker.java` . wait i will upload the file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17997/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-shashank-kadne)